# Is it a good practice to use double redirection in mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just want to remove www and force a secure connection for any page in my domain.

I'm using a double redirection for that, but I don't know if this is a good practice or it could be penalized by search engines. I'm also interested to know if there is a better way to do this:

```
# Remove www
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Force https    
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the specific url that gets redirected twice will be penalized (the url using `http` with `www`).

The resulting url (`https` without `www`) that is reached after the redirects won't be penalized.

So if your urls are already established using `https` without `www`, you won't see a penalty affect then, but if you are moving your site from `www` to without and adding `https` at the same time, you may see a temporpary penalty, it shouldn't be much though as it won't take long for the search engines to catch on that the site just moved and should retain most of it's rank.

**Edit** To do both in a single redirect you could do something like this:

```
# Force https and remove www
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you. So, you think this is the way to get both: remove www and force https?

Comment: @Memochipan Yes, I think it's fine to do it this way. You could detect both and do it in one redirect before the other two RewriteRules if you want to reduce the number of HTTP requests, but that only seems worth it if it is quite common that your users land on a url that is `http://www.` quite frequently (if there are links in that format scattered around forums for example)

Comment: No, it is not the case since most of the links come from the same site and all the links are using https without www. But, could you provide some code for showing how can we reduce the number of HTTP requests?

Comment: @Memochipan Actually I just discovered a simple way to do both, which is still quite readable by using `[OR]`. You could replace both your Rewrite blocks with the block I just added to my answer, and it should handle all three cases (`https://www`, `http://example`, and `https://example`).

Comment: In fact I was using your example but since I had many domains hosted in the same server I needed conditions for an exact match with example.com to not affect the other domains. Using the code above the other domains will use https.

Comment: @Memochipan I see, I've updated it again. That should only apply if the `Host` header ends with `.example.com` or is exactly `example.com`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very useful. One last question. Do you know if there are some rules to group the conditional [OR] and AND (by default). Because is not the same to say ((Cond1 AND Cond2) OR Cond3) or to say (Cond1 AND (Cond2 OR Cond3)). I was a little bit indecisive to use many conditions because of that.

Comment: I tested the code above and the first line is producing me problems. I think it should be `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$` to match both, with and without www.

Comment: @Memochipan I may be mistaken, but I believe that it's always as if the `OR` is in parenthesis: `Cond1 AND (Cond2 OR Cond3)`.

Comment: @Memochipan Yes, that's right. I didn't clue into the fact that your other domains are also subdomains of `example.com`.

Comment: One little thing else, there can't be a space between `!=` and `on`. At least in my server I had to use `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` but I think is a general rule according with the syntax that expects only two elements `RewriteCond TestString CondPattern`. By the way why do you prefer to use `(^www\.)?` instead of `^(www\.)?`

Comment: @Memochipan Both oh those were typos :)